# Centering an CSS arrow

Tags: html, css, centering

I've used the following code to create myself an arrow,

```
.arrow-divider{
    height:12px;
    width:12px;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    border-right:2px solid white;
    border-bottom:2px solid white;
}
```

Whenever I try to center this using `margin:0 auto` it will not center because I basically only want half of the right side of the box to be centered, but it centers the whole box, how could I fix this?

I'm currently stuck on the following code

```
<div class="box">

  <div class="center-divider"> </div>

  <div class="arrow-wrapper">
   <div class="arrow-divider"></div>  
  </div>

</div>

.box{
  position:relative;
  background:orange;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
}

.arrow-wrapper{
  display:inline-block;
}

.center-divider{
  position:absolute;
  width:6px;height:100%;
  background:red;
  left:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
.arrow-divider{
  height:12px;
  width:12px;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  border-right:2px solid black;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

I've included the following demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5aex395k/1/)

Last word, I'm not looking to use `Flexbox` and it's `align-items` and `justify-content` feature.

Edit: why the downvote?

Comment: can you provide the example of the working version (without the centering)?

Comment: @Dekel He has... there is a JSFiddle link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Dekel did you downvote? whatfor..

Comment: @MartijnEbbens, No, it did not

Comment: @Toastrackenigma he said that it worked, but he can't center it. I'm trying to understand the differences between the working version and the one that doesn't.

Comment: @Dekel I don't really see where I said that it worked, I just meant to say the arrow isn't actually centered, the box is, but the arrow not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the arrow divider is a fixed width/height of 12px... why not subtract half of it:  margin-left:-6px ?

```
.arrow-divider{
  height:12px;
  width:12px;
  margin-left:-6px;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  border-right:2px solid black;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

[Here is the updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5aex395k/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you trying to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/5aex395k/4/

I have added this two rules to `.arrow-wrapper`:

```
position: absolute;
right: 25%;
```

Your header has fixed height, so you can center the arrow vertically simply add `top` property to it.